# Docker custom user Permission Denied, while accessing container's file system

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, permission-denied

I've created a custom user using my Dockerfile. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.10

# Make /opt/ working directory in docker container.
WORKDIR /opt/

# Copy source code to image
COPY app app

# Create a user
RUN  adduser -S my_user

# Change owner and permissions
RUN chown -R my_user /opt/
RUN chmod -R 755 /opt/
USER my_user

# Start main.py script after container is up.
ENTRYPOINT python app/main.py
```

In my script, I'm creating a file in the container's `/opt/app/` directory, and this directory is mounted at host's `/var` in docker-compose using `/var/log/app:/opt/app/:z`.

When I run the container as root (without creating any users in Dockerfile), this works perfectly but using custom user, I'm getting `[Error 13] permission denied` in my script.

I've also changed the owner of the directory in Docker file and also given the permissions as `755`. So what am I missing here?

Note: I've referred to a similar question but it didn't work for me: [Cannot create directory. Permission denied inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45553074/5353128)

Answer (score 1):

You are running chown when you build the image. But you are mapping that folder as a volume when you run the container, which happens afterwards. During build time the chown runs successfully and the folder becomes owned by `my_user`, but when you run the container, the -v option overrides the container's `/opt` folder with the host's `/var`, and so the ownership and permissions of the host's folder apply.

This is because Docker builds images as a set of overlay filesystems, which become read-only when the image is built (the result of Dockerfile). When you run a container from an image, Docker adds an additional layer to that overlay filesystem stack, which is read/write. The layers above (Dockerfile) do not change the layers below (your running container), but the other way around.

More info in the [Docker overview](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/#containers).