# spring boot - docker - Logback - non root user -permission denied error

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I have the dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as build
WORKDIR /workspace/app

COPY . /workspace/app

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.gradle ./gradlew clean build -x test
RUN mkdir -p build/dependency && (cd build/dependency; jar -xf ../libs/*.jar)

WORKDIR /workspace/app/build/dependency


FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S demo && adduser -S demo -G demo
VOLUME /tmp
USER demo
ARG DEPENDENCY=/workspace/app/build/dependency

COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-noverify","-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1","-cp","app:app/lib/*","-Dspring.main.lazy-initialization=true","hello.Application"]
```

my application props has

```
logging.file.name=pafy.log
logging.file.path=logs
```

Error:

```sh
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 -t my/pmy-docker 04-07-2021 10:50:30.068
[main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application
run failed java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration
error detected: ERROR in
ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] -
openFile(pafy.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException:
pafy.log (Permission denied)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:169)
```

Please can I ask, how to fix the issue?

Note: I use demo user instead of root. could this be the problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45553149/1063509 could you please check this answer

Comment: thanks. I made the change RUN addgroup -S demo && adduser -S demo -G demo
RUN mkdir -p /logs
RUN chown demo /logs
VOLUME /logs
USER demo

Answer (score 2):

I made this change

```
RUN addgroup -S demo && adduser -S demo -G demo
RUN mkdir -p /logs
RUN chown demo /logs

VOLUME /logs
USER demo
```